# Keep AirPlay toolbar icon permanently visible or hidden

Tags: macos, airplay, menu-bar

I have a toolbar that semi-randomly every couple of minutes flips the Airplay icon on:

[image: toolbar with AirPlay]

or off again:

[image: toolbar sans AirPlay]

How do I freeze it into a state of either always on or always off? The current behaviour of occasionally shifting the seven leftmost icons a step to the left or right, because some AirPlay unit went in or out of range (or whatever's happening under the hood) is maddeningly distracting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable the icon in the menu bar by ⌘-dragging it off the menu bar, which unchecks the option in System Preferences → Displays entitled "Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available".

Should you wish to use the menu bar item, you can check this box again, or just use the AirPlay Display dropdown in System Preferences → Displays to connect to an AirPlay device.

Comment: Sweet! I had found and attempted to resolve by unchecking that checkbox before, seemingly without effect, but ⌘-dragging the icon off the menu bar when there did get rid of it (and later on re-checking the pref puts it back).

Thanks!